# AWS - where to store image/documents for application use?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a j2ee Application running on AWS,
User need to upload an image or PDF to the application for internal use,
What is the right way to get/create a path the AWS to store the images?
Images/pdf will not be exposed for anyone to download,Its just to the j2ee application

I was searching and found "buckets", but buckets are exposed to the outside world for manual upload, so i am not sure if this is the right way to go

Comment: Access to a bucket can be limited to just your app (or any entity with the proper credentials). Your app assumes credentials using various methods, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a file upload feature in your application (a page that the user can access) which streams the file to memory within the application ([example here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/) for Spring web application). Once the image is in memory, you can [store it in a secured AWS S3 bucket with the AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html).

Answer (score 2):

In AWS there are multiple storage options available. But the best option would be to use a S3 bucket. By default the S3 bucket is private and not open to outside world. You can manage permission to the bucket and authorize only your application can upload files to there and view them. There are couple of benefits when using S3 to keep file uploads.

- Extremely high durability of 99.999999999
- High availability 99.99
- High scalability
- Unlimited storage
- Low cost and event lower cost in archiving data with life cycle rules
- Versioning
  & etc.

Also you application can scale independently without limiting with storage.